# How to continue running an R script after a 1 hour pause

Tags: r

I'm downloading some kind of data from a webserver which limites the number of queries to 100 per hour.

Do you know an effective way to insert a time lag between r-script code lines to automatically run the script and gather the data after (approx.) 10 hours?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `Sys.sleep` in your script?

Comment: Consider scheduling your Rscript with TaskScheduler for Windows or cron for Mac/Linux. Yes, R code can be automated with `Rscript.exe`.

Comment: @Parfait I took a look on TaskScheduler but was not able for mac. Thanks for the suggestion with cron! I'm going to test it and post the result if succeeds or not.

Comment: If you want to stay inside R, r2evans is correct. I have used it this way in the long past (no example at this remove). See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Sys.sleep (You'll want 36000 seconds.)

Comment: @JohnGarland @r2evans Thanks for your answers! I think your solution is the most optimal to solve my problem. Just adding `Sys.sleep(time)` between my loops to obtain data the problem is solved. Many thanks again for your help!